# Can't get data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm connected to **phpmyadmin** but I can not get any data from phpmyadmin.
my **php** version is ***7.2.9*** , I made everything that I wanted in database but php can't show the data in site ( I'm using localhost ). 
here is the code:

```
    <?php
    $key = $_GET['key'];

    $terms = explode(" ", $key);
    $query = "SELECT * FORM search WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;
        if($i == 1){
            $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        } else{
            $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        }
        echo $query;
    }

    //connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db('search');
    $query = mysqli_query($query);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);



    if($numrows > 0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</h2></a>
        $description<br /><br />";
        }
        }
        else{ 
        echo "No results found for \"<b>$key</b>\""; }

    //disconnect
    mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Do you mean *MySQL* ?

Comment: @AymDev yes , exactly!

Comment: @AymDev sorry , I'm new in php and MySQL

Comment: Do you actually see the "No results found for x" message? Or do you see another error?

Comment: @DirkScholten I see (No result found for "x") , actually I'm going to make a search engine

Comment: you are connecting through mysql but querying through mysqli

Comment: There is also a typo in your query `FORM` instead of `FROM`.

Comment: @DirkScholten That's just a pasting problem , that's FROM , now I entered FORM

Comment: From a quick look I think there is an Issue in the Query... if i is NOT EQUAL TO 1 .... I think there should be some word before the 'or'. Otherwise the Query seems incomplete.. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes in your PHP/HTML. I'm gonna sum them up here so you can take a look at them:

- `<h2><a href='$link'>$title</h2></a>$description<br /><br />` This is wrong HTML. Close your `a` tag inside the `h2`.
- You are connecting to you database through `mysql`, but querying through `mysqli`. Connect to your database with `mysqli`. `Mysql_` family of functions have been removed in PHP 7
- You have a typo in your query. you have written `FORM` instead of `FROM`.
- You are exploding your `$_GET` variable on spaces. But i doubt if a `$_GET` variable has any spaces to begin with... Check if this is true.

Comment: Thank's for your help :) , I wrote FORM wrong here , it's correct in my code
I will correct all of them now :) , thank you again

Comment: The `$i` is a check for first instance for the wording of the SQL

Answer (score 0):

first of all mysql_connect() is not anymore available after php 5. Instead of using mysql use mysqli_connect(). Please how to make connection and query database using php7 here.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_row.asp

If still you have problem. Ask for help in comments.

```
   <?php

    $query = "SELECT * FORM search WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;
        if($i == 1){
            $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        } else{
            $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        }
        echo $query;
    }

    //connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","search");
    if(!$conn)die("Connection Error");
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if(!query)die("query error");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</h2></a>
        $description<br /><br />";
        }
        }
        else{ 
        echo "No results found for \"<b>$key</b>\""; 
        }
```

Comment: Anshu -- please only post code that has fixed the problem -- what has changed in your code? I see you're still using `mysql_connect()`...

Comment: @Martin Sorry it was a typo. Thanks for figuring out

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up mysqli and mysql. I have edited your stuff. Please  try. Don't forget to fix the portion marked [missing]

```
      <?php
       $key = $_GET['key'];

       $terms = explode(" ", $key);


      foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;
        if($i == 1){  
           $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
       } else{
          $query .= " description OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
       }
         echo $query;
        }

      //connection
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysqli_select_db($conn, 'search');
       if($result= mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
          $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
       }




        if($numrows > 0){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];    
                //echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</h2></a>
                //$description<br /><br />";
                echo '<h2><a href="' . $link . '">' . $title . 
                '</h2></a>' .  $description . '<br /><br />';
              }
            }
             else{ 
              echo "No results found for \"<b>$key</b>\""; }

           //disconnect
            mysqli_close();

           ?>
```

Comment: Thank you dude :) , let me do it.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work again, Really I don't know where is my problem! 
It's two days that I'm angry because of this.
I can't find the solution
Do you think that this problem is because of MySQL?

Comment: Have you fixed the [missing] part? Also I haven't checked the final echo for any single quote double quote issues..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Full working Example TESTED at my end (Last night I wasn't at my work machine and couldn't test the code.Later I created a small db and Tested it. I had searched with the dummy key 'ram mary albert' in my example

```
    <?php
        $key = $_GET['key'];

        $terms = explode(" ", $key);

        $qu1 = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";
        $qu2 = "order  by id ASC";



        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

        mysqli_select_db($conn, 'search');

        for($i=0; $i< count($terms);  $i++){

          $query = $qu1 . " keywords LIKE '%$terms[$i]%'  "  .  $qu2;

          echo( $query . "<br>" );

          $resulter= mysqli_query($conn, $query);

          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulter)){;

                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];    

                $EscLink='\'' . $link . '\'';

                echo ('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="alert(' . 
                $EscLink . ')">' . $title .  '</a><br>' .  $description . 
                '<br /><br />');


           } // Close While
         } // Close for



         //disconnect
         mysqli_close($conn);

         ?>
```

[image: See the SCREENSHOT of the result]